# Create a task if a particular if a date lapses? Scheduled APEX the only option?

Tags: apex, workflow, scheduled-apex

I feel like I may be missing something obvious here, but I have a certain field that is populated with a future date. I would like to ensure that follow-up tasks are created when that due date lapses, i.e. it is not updated to a date further in the future. Note that there is no activity on the record that would cause a workflow rule to fire.

Is creating an APEX job the only solution for this? I would have figured that there would have been some kind of platform-based tool that would address this as it seems like it would be a fairly common use case.

Comment: What causes the date to be updated further in the future? Why does a workflow rule not satisfy your needs?

Comment: A user would update that information, but assuming that they had, you wouldn't want that task to be created, or send a reminder if an update had been made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Time Based workflow for this scenario, say if xDateField(your date field) when lapse you can set a Time Based workflow as shown below

[image]

To avoid this workflow to trigger once changed to future date, you can set a condition as well.
Time Based Workflow Examples : https://c-praveenkumar-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/img/actions_example.png
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=workflow_rules_new.htm&type=5